# Nested Array's and Matching Values

Tags: python, arrays

Hello I have two data sets that I need to match up, and their corresponding values need to be identical.

```
list1 = [['Bob',[1,2,3,4]],['henry',[65,23,41,23]],['jerry',[5,8,10,12]]]

list2 = [['Bob',[1,2,4,3]],['jill',[36,21,34,53]],['jerry',[9,8,4,12]]]
```

However there is a caveat, if the value associated with the name does not exist when comparing list1 and list2 it needs to be checked and then added to the list and vice versa.

For instance, 'jerry' exists in both list1 and list2 however  [5,8,10,12] is not equal to [9,8,4,12], the desired update appended to both list1 and list2 would be: [9,4,5,8,10,12] so both lists that have values associated with 'jerry' that now match. The order of the values associated with the name does not matter in the circumstances I am working with.

This is a real world problem that I have translated into a fairly simple data set. I appreciate any tips or advice!

Output Intended:

```
list1 = [['Bob',[1,2,3,4]],['henry',[65,23,41,23]],['jerry',[4,5,8,9,10,12]]]

list2 = [['Bob',[1,2,3,4]],['jill',[36,21,34,53]],['jerry',[4,5,8,9,10,12]]]]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post for how to ask better questions, which will help people give you better answers. In particular, it's good to show what you've already tried (i.e. your code).

Comment: What should happen in case the name can be found from only one of the lists? Like `jill` and `henry` in your example. It would greatly help if you could provide the expected output in the same format as the input.

Comment: Added expected output. If the name and value associated with the name exists in one list, but not the other, it should be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()`

`list3 =  {k:list(set([list1[k]+list2[k])) for k in list1}`

sorry I made this weird assumption you were using a dictionary...

`list3 =  [[k,list(set([list1[k]+list2[k]))] for k in list1]`

that's better, oh wait no it's not...

`list3 =  [[list1[n][0],list(set([list1[n][1]+list2[n][1]]))] for n,k in enumerate(list1)]`

dear lord, is there a reason you aren't using dictionaries here?

Comment: typo: `list2[k]))`

Comment: list3 =  [[k,list(set([list1[k]+list2[k]))] for k in list1], doesnt work, you cannot iter through like that since list1[k] must be a numerical value e.g. k is not a key value.

Comment: yes, there is a reason, I wish a dictionary was possible.. but since you cannot nest a list into a dictionary e.g. a key must have a hash value according to other post's. I will try this out, I am looking for the most elegant solution so far I am liking what I am seeing! Also the numbers are actually suppose to represent IP-addresses but I made them numbers to simplify the question.

Comment: @BobHenderson The key of your dictionaries would be the name, right? So that's a string and has a hash value. Where's the problem? You can have lists as values in dictionaries, and you can have dictionaries as values in lists as well.